# How to prevent AJAX long poll from stopping to work or resuming after device (PC, tablet) wakes up

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile, long-polling

I have a page which needs to display text that is generated from the my site, re-displaying the text if the state on the server changes. I've decided to implement is as a long poll (due to server limitations), and it works fine until a device (PC or Tablet) goes to sleep. Once the device is woken up, the polling is not resumed. Any idea how this can be fixed? 
Here is the way I use the long poll. Both using **"complete: "** (currently commented in AJAX) and explicitly calling **poll()** function is showing the same results. (the site uses jquery mobile on front-end).

Thank you!

```
<div data-role="content">

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" readonly="readonly" value="willBeChanged"  />
    </div>

</div>
<script>


(function(){
function poll() {
        $.ajax({ 
        url: "/app/myTextUpdate",
    success: function(data){
                var myTextValueTxtBox = document.getElementById("myText");
                myTextValueTxtBox.value = data.myText + " " + data.Time;                    
            }, 
        dataType: "json", 
        //complete: poll(), 
        timeout: 30000,
        error: function (response) {
              var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
              console.log("myText: " + r.myText);
              console.log("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
              console.log("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
              setTimeout(function() { poll() },300);
            },
        parseerror: function() {
                console.log("Cannot parse response");
                window.location.replace("/app/viewBoard");
                setTimeout(function() { poll() },300);
            },

        cache: false
        });
    }

    poll();

})();

</script>
```